How can I ask OpenTripPlanner to prefer itineraries with frequent routes?
I am trying to plan a journey between certain points, however, the obvious routes all involve using connections with only run every half an hour.
How can I make OpenTripPlanner to prefer routes which run more frequently, even if it has other undesirable features such as more transfers? I am using OpenTripPlanner version 2.4 with HSL GraphQL API.

Could you include a code sample of what you're currently trying to do?
